# Recursive loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, recursion

I try to write certain attributes to html with recursive loop, but can't make the code work :(

I have array of hashes as you can see in Json. With following attributes: serno - serial number, parent_serno - serial number of parent, name - name of the attribute. I want to first write down every hash.name that has "parent_serno == 0" and then after each one I want to write name of hashes that have "parent_serno = serno(of first hash)" it's kind of grouping them up according to serno and parent_serno.

Can you guys tell me what I do wrong?

```
 var dataBase = [{"serno": 1, "parent_serno": 0, "name": "Home"},
            {"serno": 2, "parent_serno": 0, "name": "Search"},
                {"serno": 10, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Search Payment"},
            {"serno": 11, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Problematic Search Payment"},
            {"serno": 12, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Cash Error"},
            {"serno": 13, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Payment Note"},
            {"serno": 89, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Search Payment By Category"},
            {"serno": 131, "parent_serno": 2, "name": "Search Payment New"},
            {"serno": 3, "parent_serno": 0, "name": "User Mangement"},
            {"serno": 4, "parent_serno": 0, "name": "Service Provider"},
            {"serno": 5, "parent_serno": 0, "name": "General"},
            {"serno": 88, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "Balance and Financial"},
            {"serno": 14, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "My Subagents"},
            {"serno": 15, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "My Providers"},
            {"serno": 16, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "My Dealers"},
            {"serno": 17, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "My Wallets"},
            {"serno": 19, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "Accounts"},
            {"serno": 45, "parent_serno": 19, "name": "Bank Accounts"},
            {"serno": 46, "parent_serno": 19, "name": "Transfers"},
            {"serno": 0, "parent_serno": 5, "name": "My Statements"},
            {"serno": 47, "parent_serno": 20, "name": "My Terminals"}];

        var funkcia = function(parent) {
            for (var i=0, i < dataBase.length, i++){
                if (dataBase[i].parent_serno == parent){
                    document.write(dataBase[i].name);
                    parent = dataBase[i].serno;
                    funkcia(parent);
                };
                  };
                    };

funkcia(0);
```

Comment: Don't use semicolons `;` after closing brackets `}` when closing a block...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  parent = dataBase[i].serno;
>  funkcia(parent);
> ```

This is your problem. You're altering the `parent` variable, but then let the for-loop run on, now searching for the wrong `parent`.

Either you use a different variable:

```
function funkcia(parent) {
    for (var i=0; i < dataBase.length; i++){
        if (dataBase[i].parent_serno == parent){
            document.write(dataBase[i].name);
            var new_parent = dataBase[i].serno;
            funkcia(new_parent);
        }
    }
}
```

or none at all:

```
function funkcia(parent) {
    for (var i=0; i < dataBase.length; i++){
        if (dataBase[i].parent_serno == parent){
            document.write(dataBase[i].name);
            funkcia(dataBase[i].serno);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but putting break doesn't seem to solve the problem :(

Comment: Right, of course not. Fixed now. But notice that this will still not work as expected, because your `dataBase` does a have a circular relation between `My Statements` and `General`.

Comment: Yeah I guess I mistyped it. my statements should have serno = 0;

Comment: You might want to update your question with a corrected database then.

Comment: Home | Search | Search Payment | Problematic Search Payment | Cash Error | Payment Note | Search Payment By Category | Search Payment New | User Mangement | Service Provider | General | My Wallets | Accounts | Bank Accounts | Transfers | My Statements | Home | Search | Search Payment | Problematic Search Payment | Cash Error | Payment Note | Search Payment By Category | Search Payment New | User Mangement | Service Provider | General | My Wallets | Accounts | Bank Accounts | Transfers | My Statements.

I get this output... it is still buggy, but its closer :)

thank you for the answer bergi.